# LayoutInflater of a GridView rows

Tags: android, gridview, layout-inflater

If I use LayoutInflate to show all items of a ListView component whit ViewHolder class

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_items, null);
```

What should I use if I need to show a list using GridView?

I am trying to build a soccer standings table like this:

[image]

Comment: you can use ListView with custom layout

Comment: Seeing the soccer table, using ListView is THE BEST idea. If you have implemented for ListView, I suggest not to change to GridView, that's really a bad idea.

Comment: did u create two layout?

Comment: Yes @MohammodHossain, I worked with a ListView with fragments days ago and I did the same with this table. Only I need to align all numbers vertically as the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListView is the best solution . You will create two layout.
```

One layout for Listview with header and other layout for representing for every row coloumn.
    Such one layout is soccer.xml and child layout is soccer_item.xml

**soccer.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"        
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTeamName"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="Team"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtResultValue"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
            android:gravity="center"          
            android:text="@string/result_value"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
            android:gravity="center"          
            android:text="MP"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtW"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"

            android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
            android:gravity="center"           
            android:text="W" 
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/scorrorList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#FFF" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**soccer_item.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTeamName"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:text="Team"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResultValue"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
        android:gravity="center"          
        android:text="@string/result_value"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMp"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
        android:gravity="center"          
        android:text="MP"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtW"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.24"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sub_header_selector"
        android:gravity="center"           
        android:text="W" 
        android:textColor="@color/Black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need to do this but using RelativeLayout

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `TableLayout` instead of `GridView`.

B'coz in `GridView` `Hetrogeneous` view is not possible.

Go through [Table Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

Or else you can use Custom `ListView`

Comment: What is better between TableLayout and ListView?

Comment: @JohnB you can use ListView.

Comment: What I should do to get similar data aligned vertically as shown in the graphic?